# to read a property file present in a dynamic web project from a jar added to the project

Tags: java, jar

i am working on a dynamic web project(DWP) which has a property file.  have created a jar that should read the contents of the property file in the DWP and the changes in the property file and incorporate the changes in the DWP.I am not able to read the property file from the jar. I want to know how a jar in  a DWP read  a property file of the DWP

here's the code opf the jar

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

public class fileReader extends Thread 
{
    publicstatic long oldTMS;
    long currentTMS;
    File file;
    public static long limit;
    //static String Path = "./configuration/RequestLimit.properties";
    static String Path="configuration/RequestLimit.properties";
    public static Properties properties;    
    public fileReader() throws IOException, InterruptedException {    
        System.out.println("Reading the property file for the first time");
        Thread thread = new Thread();
        setDaemon(true);    
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(Path);
        System.out.println("fd:"+in.getFD());
        properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(in);
        String requestLimit = properties.getProperty("RequestLimit");           
        System.out
                .println("request limit as read from the property file is ----"
                        + requestLimit);
        limit = Long.parseLong(properties.getProperty("RequestLimit"));    
        System.out.println("request limit as per the  reading is ---" + limit);
        start();
        // waits for the thread to die
        join();    
    }    
    public void run() {    
        System.out.println(" thread starts");
        if (Thread.currentThread().isDaemon()) {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    System.out.println("entered in infinite loop");
                    file = new File(Path);
                    System.out.println("file name is --------" + file);
                    currentTMS = file.lastModified();
                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "E yyyy.MM.dd 'at' hh:mm:ss a zzz");    
                    System.out.println("file initial change time stamp:::::"
                            + dateFormat.format(currentTMS));    
                    try {    
                        System.out
                                .println("lets see if the file has changed or not !!");    
                        FileInputStream d = new FileInputStream(file);    
                        if (oldTMS != currentTMS) {
                            System.out.println("checking for old and new time stamp!");    
                            oldTMS = currentTMS;    
                            System.out.println("file modified last at-----------"
                                            + oldTMS);
                            // reload property
                            try {    
                                System.out.println("Reloading property file");
                                properties.load(d);    
                                System.out.println("After Reloading property file properties : "
                                                + properties
                                                        .getProperty("RequestLimit"));    
                                limit = Long.parseLong(properties
                                        .getProperty("RequestLimit"));
                                System.out.println("request limit as per the  reading is ---"
                                                + limit);    
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e2) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }    
            }
        }    
    }    
}
```

using jar in the DWP like this

```
package com.ING;    
import java.io.IOException;    
import com.change.fileReader;    
public class deamonCaller
{    
    public long callDeamon() throws IOException, InterruptedException 
    {
        fileReader fr = new fileReader();
         Long requestLimit =fileReader.limit;
        return requestLimit;            
    }    
}
```

Comment: Provide your folder structure, where your properties exist?

Comment: how can i uplaod a pic here. have never uploded pic

Comment: there is a folder configuration in WEB INF . that folder has the property file

Answer (score 1):

Please try with below code. I hope, it will help you alot.

```
static String Path="configuration/RequestLimit.properties";
loadProperties(Path);     

private void loadProperties(String propertiesName) {

        if (properties != null) {
            return;
        }

        // Properties properties = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(propertiesName);
        if (inputStream == null) {
            throw new Exception(propertiesName + "something");
        }

        properties = new Properties();
        try {
            properties.load(inputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is  not giving  null pointer exceptions. one more thing when i use "get resource as stream " and change the property file the change is not reflected

Comment: Null pointer exception?? This is just replace to your properties file read code.Not overwrite to all.

Comment: i did that but its not running at all. basically i want to read a property file and the changes to that prop file in a dynamic web project from a jar. when i add thsi jar to the web project system throws an exception : file not found

Comment: the code  in tha jar works fine but when i add it to the web project the jar is not able to locate the property file

Comment: your properties file in java class path?

Comment: it's strange because this code work in my jar and work properly.

Comment: Hey, Please change "configuration/RequestLimit.properties"; to "/configuration/RequestLimit.properties"; How??

Comment: i should shar the directory structure i guess

Comment: i have tried "/configuration/RequestLimit.properties" even then its not working.. tats wat i was thinking how to share the folder structure

Comment: there is a folder configuration in WEB INF . that folder has the property file

Comment: this properties file must have in java class path. did you?not in WEB INF direcotry.

Answer (score 0):

Provide the path as a -Dproperty=..... to java nad then read it from there instead of hardcode the value.

Answer (score 0):

well for those who may get stuck like me. it was a serendipity for me . Was explainig the prob to a senior when an idea clicked my head , implemented and it worked .. anyways heres a solution.

place the Propertyfile in web content directly,no need to put the file in a folder in the dynamic web project. In the Servelet of the Dynamic Web proj(DWP) use the following lines of code :

```
String pathPropertyFile = request.getSession().getServletContext()
                .getRealPath("")
                + "\\RequestLimit.properties";
        System.out.println("path of the property file is"+pathforFileReader);
```

pass this  PATH obtained as "pathPropertyFile" to the class of the jar that has the code for reading the property file. 
i have used a Bean class , set the path in the beann and then feth the path from  the bean and pass it to the method of the JAR class that reads the property file.

```
public class deamonCaller {


    public long callDeamon(Tao tao) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        // obtain the path from the bean Tao
        String Path = tao.getPath();
        System.out.println("path in deamon:" + Path);
        // call the jar method while passing PATH as a parameter
        fileReader fr = new fileReader(Path);

        Long requestLimit = fileReader.limit;
        return requestLimit;

    }

}
```

CODE of The FILE READER

```
package com.change;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

public class fileReader extends Thread {
    static long oldTMS;
    long currentTMS;
    File file;
    public static long limit;
    //static String Path = "./configuration/RequestLimit.properties";
     public static String pathName;
    public static Properties properties;

    public fileReader(String Path) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        pathName=Path;
        System.out.println("Reading the property file for the first time");
        Thread thread = new Thread();
        setDaemon(true);

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(pathName);
        System.out.println("fd:"+in.getFD());
        properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(in);
        String requestLimit = properties.getProperty("RequestLimit");

        System.out
                .println("request limit as read from the property file is ----"
                        + requestLimit);
        limit = Long.parseLong(properties.getProperty("RequestLimit"));

        System.out.println("request limit as per the  reading is ---" + limit);
        start();
        // waits for the thread to die
        join();

    }

    public void run() {

        System.out.println(" thread starts");
        if (Thread.currentThread().isDaemon()) {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    System.out.println("entered in infinite loop");
                    file = new File(pathName);
                    System.out.println("file name is --------" + file);
                    currentTMS = file.lastModified();
                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "E yyyy.MM.dd 'at' hh:mm:ss a zzz");

                    System.out.println("file initial change time stamp:::::"
                            + dateFormat.format(currentTMS));

                    try {

                        System.out
                                .println("lets see if the file has changed or not !!");

                        FileInputStream d = new FileInputStream(file);

                        if (oldTMS != currentTMS) {
                            System.out
                                    .println("checking for old and new time stamp!");

                            oldTMS = currentTMS;

                            System.out
                                    .println("file modified last at-----------"
                                            + oldTMS);
                            // reload property
                            try {

                                System.out.println("Reloading property file");
                                properties.load(d);

                                System.out
                                        .println("After Reloading property file properties : "
                                                + properties
                                                        .getProperty("RequestLimit"));

                                limit = Long.parseLong(properties
                                        .getProperty("RequestLimit"));
                                System.out
                                        .println("request limit as per the  reading is ---"
                                                + limit);

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

    }

}
```